# How to recursivly delete all JPG files, but keep the ones containing "sample"

Tags: linux, bash, regex, rm

How can I find and delete all the `.jpg` files in a directory tree with the exception of the ones containing "sample" in their filename?

For example :

```
a.zip          ->  keep it  
b.jpg          ->  delete it  
a-sample.jpg   ->  keep it  
b-Sample.jpg   ->  keep it
```

Comment: Do you mean `a-sample.jpg` and `b-Sample.jpg`?

Comment: Yes I forgot to type the .jpg for a-sample.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete all files ending in .`jpg` (case-insensitive) except for files with `sample` in the file name (case-insensitive:

```
find . ! -iname '*sample*'  -iname '*.jpg' -delete
```

This recurses through all directories in the tree starting at the current directory.

How it works:

- `.`

  This specifies that we start with the current directory.
- `! -iname '*sample*'`

  This instructs `find` to ignore all files with `sample` in their name.  The `i` in `-iname` makes this test case-Insensitive.
- `-iname '*.jpg'`

  This condition, which is and'd with the previous one, looks for files ending in `.jpg`.
- `-delete`

  This instructs `find` to delete all such files.

Before running the above command, you might want to test it.  Run:

```
find . ! -iname '*sample*'  -iname '*.jpg'
```

This will print out the files of interest.  If this list is good, then run the command again with `-delete` appended.

Comment: Really right: it's never enough to remember to try before then to act, even more if the action is to delete. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can use

```
shopt -s extglob
```

to enable negative matching:

```
rm !(*[Ss]ample*).jpg
```

To match subfolders too, turn on

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and use the double star:

```
rm **/!(*[Ss]ample*).jpg
```

Comment: I should only suggest the OP to try in advance with `ls **/!(*[Ss]ample*).jpg` and only after checking to repeat the command with `rm`... just to be protected by typos.